How to do smooth merging of two points using tikzpicture
I'm drawing this figure using tikzpicture. My codes are as follows,
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \draw[thick,->](-0.5,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$z$};
        \draw[thick,->](0,-7) -- (0,7) node[left] {$t$};
    
    \path (0,4.0) coordinate (A) node[left] {$A$}
           (0,-4.0) coordinate (B) node[left] {$B$}
           (3.9,0.2) coordinate (zs) node[right] {$z_*$}
           (9,6) coordinate (T1) node[right] {$\frac{T}{2}$}
            (9,-6) coordinate (T2) node[right] {$-\frac{T}{2}$}
            (0,-7) coordinate (zinf) node[below] {$z=\infty$};
             \draw[smooth,blue,thick] (A) to[bend left=10] (T1);
            \draw[blue,thick] (B) to[bend right=10] (T2);
          
        \begin{scope}[rotate=180, shift={(-6, 0)}]
           \draw[thick,red] plot[domain=1:5, samples=100]({\x+1},{2*sqrt(\x-1)});
           \draw[thick,red] plot[domain=1:5, samples=100]({\x+1},{-2*sqrt(\x-1)});
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The output is given as this.

But I want a smooth merging of red and blue curves at A and B, as shown in the following image.

Can anyone suggest something how to do it? I've tried with \draw plot [smooth] and \draw[rounded corners=10pt] as well, but it's coming the same.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Thank you so much for your feedback; I've incorporated the essentials.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick, ->] (-0.5,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$z$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,-7) -- (0,7) node[left] {$t$};

\coordinate (A) at (0,4);
\coordinate (B) at (0,-4);
\coordinate (zs) at (4,0);
\coordinate (T1) at (9,6);
\coordinate (T2) at (9,-6);

\node[left] at (A) {$A$};
\node[left] at (B) {$B$};
\node[right] at (zs) {$z_*$};
\node[right] at (T1) {$\frac{T}{2}$};
\node[right] at (T2) {$-\frac{T}{2}$};
\node[below] at (0,-7) {$z=\infty$};

\draw[blue, thick] (T1) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=0.5] (A);
\draw[blue, thick] (T2) to[out=180, in=-90, looseness=0.5] (B);
\draw[red, thick] (A) to[out=-90, in=90, looseness=0.5] (zs) to[out=-90, in=90, looseness=0.5] (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



The first step was to draw the whole curve in one go. Then I used clipping rectangles to separate the blue and red versions.
There was a bit of overshoot at (A) and (B) which had to be compensated by moving the target points.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \draw[thick,->](-0.5,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$z$};
        \draw[thick,->](0,-7) -- (0,7) node[left] {$t$};
    
    \path (0,4.0) coordinate (A) node[left] {$A$}
           (0,-4.0) coordinate (B) node[left] {$B$}
           (3.9,0.2) coordinate (zs) node[right] {$z_*$}
           (9,6) coordinate (T1) node[right] {$\frac{T}{2}$}
            (9,-6) coordinate (T2) node[right] {$-\frac{T}{2}$}
            (0,-7) coordinate (zinf) node[below] {$z=\infty$};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (A) rectangle (T1) (B) rectangle (T2);
      \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{(T1)(0.07,4.1)(4,0)(0.07,-4.1)(T2)};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (A) rectangle (B-|T2);
      \draw[red,thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{(T1)(0.07,4.1)(4,0)(0.07,-4.1)(T2)};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


